# How to add all elements of an ArrayList into another ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, addition

I'm trying to add all the elements of an ArrayList into another ArrayList,

I've tried using

```
if (!listTwo.isEmpty()){
    finalList.addAll(listTwo);
    }

finalList.addAll(listTwo);
```

However, this keeps sending me an NullPointerException error. 
Both are ArryList, and listTwo does have elements inside of it.

Any idea why it's sending this exception?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Show us the exception. And perhaps finalList is null ?

Comment: have you initialized both your lists?

Comment: Check if finalList and listTwo are not nulls. They could be empty but not null.

Comment: If they are empty then you will not get a NPE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
finalList.addAll(listTwo);
```

Will add the elements from `listTwo` into `finalList`.

If you are getting a NullPointerException it is because one of your lists is null. Note that `isEmpty()` will throw a NullPointerException if the list is null, so that probably won't help you.

To check if the lists are null, do `listTwo == null` and/or `finalList == null`.

Comment: Thanks! I was initizalizing both of my ArrayList with null